# Using wgets to connect to sites in a txt file using shell scripting

Tags: file, shell, scripting

I am trying to create a script that uses wgets to access every url from a list in a file. However when doing this instead of accessing website.com it will try to connect to website.com/r/n. I know this has to do with text formatting in the text editor but I'm unsure of how to get my program to ignore this. This is the code I have:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for i in `cat $1`
    do
    wget --spider $i 
    if wget --spider $i 2>&1 | grep --quiet "200 OK" ; then
        echo $i >> connected.txt
    else
        echo $i >> unsuccesful.txt
    fi
    rm wget-log
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your script

```
dos2unix "$1"
```

IHTH